# Offset() undefined, div внутри td

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, не пойму почему у div, который я добавляю внутрь td не определено свойство offset? div'ы добавляются и нормально отображаются. Вот код:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
        if ($('#FIO' + i).length) {
            $('#FIO' + i).append('<div id=st'+i+'>СТАТУС</div>');
            $('#st' + i).css('position', 'absolute');
        }
     }

     $(window).on('load', function() {
        for (i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
            if ($('#FIO' + i).length) {
                $('#st' + i).css('visibility', 'hidden');
                $('#st' + i).css('left', $('FIO' + i).css('left'));
                //$('#st' + i).css('top', (parseFloat($('st' + i).offset().top) + 10) + 'px');
                $('#st' + i).css('border', '1px solid black');
                $('#st' + i).css('background', 'white');
                $('#FIO' + i).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                offset = $('st' + i).offset();
                console.log(offset.top);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `$('st'` .......`$('#st'` - разница видна?

Comment: Да, видна .............................................................................................!!! Извиняюсь за тупость)

Comment: Уважаемые пользователи. Если вы получили ответ на свой вопрос, просьба не забывать помечать его как ответ! Это важно!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) При добавлении div элементов добавляйте для id кавычки:

```
$('#FIO' + i).append('<div id="st'+i+'">СТАТУС</div>');
```

2) Когда вы динамически обращаетесь к элементам:

```
$('#st' + i).css('left', $('FIO' + i).css('left'));
$('st' + i).offset();
```

указывайте их принадлежность к классу: `$('.FIO' + i)` или id `$('#FIO' + i)`

Удачи ;)

Comment: И про кавычки забыл(, спасибо.